# NuxtJs Url changes but page no

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

The NuxtJs app works well with javascript enabled in the localhost and in the server, but I am trying to make it work with Javascript disabled.

I switch to SSR mode, in localhost I can browse all the pages (without javascript) but when I deploy it to the server with `npm run build` works well with javascript enabled but when I disabled it, the URL changes but the page is reloaded in the home page (no change on the content).

Here is a Github repo of an example:
[Nuxt App Github repo](https://github.com/ynsmtkl/nuxt_app)

Preview of this repo:
[Preview of the nuxt app](https://test.lilified.com/)

Here is what I get on Network inspector when I try to access for example to Brands page:

[image]

Comment: Sure, here is the link: lilified.com

Comment: @tony19 Please take a look at the Github repo and the preview of the app, I edited the question.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your server configuration. How does it serve the Nuxt app? Is it actually running Node, or just serving static content?

Comment: Thank you for replay. As you can see on the link, it's just a simple app with three static pages, and the main app is combining NuxtJs and Laravel both don't work without Javascript enabled. Please do you have a suggest from where in the server the issue comes?

Comment: The reason I suspect it's to do with the server configuration is that if you download /brands when running locally, you will see that it has "Brands" in the h1, but if you download it from the server, it has "Home" in the h1. If Node is in fact running, that could point to there being a problem with the way the app receives routes from the URL. Is it behind NGINX or Apache? If so, how is that configured?

Answer (score 0):

Am using Nuxt 2 and the issue was I was using the fragment npm package on my layouts. After swapping the fragment component with an HTML element e.g. section, nuxt-link now works like a charm.

nuxt-link requires you have only a single parent. But fragment was commenting on the actual DOM. Check your default layout and make sure you are using a single parent.

Answer (score -1):

You need to see [YOUR-PROJECT]/.nuxt/router.js file of your project which is auto-generated routing. In this file you can find your auto-generated route urls and names. And in nuxt-link, please use route name instead path.

Further information -> https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#basic-routes

also add watchQuery

```
export default {
 watchQuery: ['page', 'order', 'q']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even I did that doesn't work, everything works well with javascript enabled but when it is disabled.